# Stop using Mac keyboard Option as a modifier to character

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I don't want to use the feature in Mac Keyboard that replace Option+a with å. 
(For example, imagine I want to quickly press the button Repl&ace All in NetBeans)
How can I have Mac stop do such thing?

*Edited:*
My question arose out of this situation:
I use Replace functionality in NetBeans.
When I'm at the replace text box, I'm typing something. When I'm done, I invoke the Replace All button by press Option+A in the keyboard. Netbeans understand it as it perform replace all features. However, right before that, the å character (as a result of pressing Option+A) is appended to the replacement, make such process incorrect. I don't need to type a special character right now, so I want to stop it. Wouldn't it be more sensible if such feature can be turned on/off with another shortcut key?

Comment: Experienced with both Windows and Ubuntu, I find Mac have very nasty philosophy: No cut files using keyboard, no default keyboard shortcut for maximize windows. Alt+Tab is nasty when an application have multiple windows.

Comment: Isn't rel&ace cmd A not option A?

Comment: No cut files using keyboard? The ability to potentially lose a file by overwriting the clipboard is a good thing? It's easy to add a shortcut to maximize windows. What do you mean alt-tab is nasty? Do you mean command-tab? Command-` cycles through open windows of an application, command-tab cycles through open applications. This is much better than the windows way.

Comment: (In Windows, when you "cut" a file it doesn't go anywhere until you "paste" it. If you overwrite the clipboard, nothing happens to the file.)

Comment: +1 For Cmd+`, I didn't know about it before. Thx. But wait, why don't mac just set the default keyboard for maximize windows instead of "easy to add"? We have one 20 iMac here and you expect us to go around and "easy-to-add" whenever we need to work on another iMac?

Comment: @Phuong I suspect the reason why there is no default shortcut for maximize window is because on the Macintosh, it isn't necessary as it is on Windows, and is discouraged. The menu bar is not tied to the window and is always seen at the top of the screen.

Comment: On the Macintosh, the maximize window button usually only maximizes the window as much as necessary to view the window contents, and doesn't try and fill the screen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876485/how-to-disable-typing-special-characters-when-pressing-option-key-in-mac-os-x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The <kbd>alt</kbd> key on the Macintosh is primarily used for international character keyboard mapping. This is a much more sane and reasonable approach to extended characters than windows alt-numpad tricks. Because of this, it is not typically used alone as a keyboard shortcut key (except with Function keys), although it is used in some shortcuts in conjunction with <kbd>command</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd>.

Keyboard remapping can be done with a utility called Ukelele:

http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele

However, this won't help you, since you are expecting the <kbd>alt</kbd> key to act like a shortcut (command/control) key.

There is a free utility that lets you swap around modifier keys, if their placement is unfamiliar to you:

http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/

Here's the Netbeans article explaining MacOS X keyboard shortcuts, and how to adjust either the Netbeans shortcuts or the Mac OSX shortcuts:

http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/mac.html

EDIT:
Solution for button shortcuts in netbeans dialog boxes.

OK, so the Netbeans IDE is a brain-dead cross-platform java application. Ensure you don't have a text field highlighted before using the alt-key button shortcuts. This can be quickly accomplished by hitting <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>.

Comment: Hmm, Cmd as a short cut? Is there any thing wrong with my keyboard, because when I press Command+T in Firefox, it open a new tab (which is equivalent to Ctrl+Tab in both Windows & Ubuntu).

Comment: This is expected behaviour. Generally, Command is the key used for system-wide shortcuts on the Mac. (Instead of control…)

Comment: I have looked at your suggested solutions but none is what I expected. I have modified the question so that you can understand my problem more clear.

Comment: @Phuong I've downloaded NetBeans to see what you're talking about. Ok, so this is shortcuts for buttons in a dialog. Honestly, this isn't a MacOSX problem, this is a NetBeans problem (Brain dead shortcuts in a Java-based application). All regular Macintosh applications use command-key for button shortcuts. I have a solution, hit tab so the highlighted control isn't a text field. Then use the Alt-A shortcut.

Comment: Cool, I never think about that. It adds more keystrokes, though. I find it common with Mac. For example, in Windows, I can hold Shift+Ctrl+End to select till the end of text, then release Shift and press X to cut it. But in Mac OSX, I must release both Shift & Option & then hold Command + X. Well, and the fastest to open the menu is Ctrl+F2 then (Left+Right)xn times. Oh, c'mon Mac OSX.

Comment: @Phuong Yes there are different conventions in Mac OSX that take getting used to for a windows user. In Mac OS X to do what you describe is command-shift-right arrow to select until end of line, then command-X to cut. Very similar to windows and just as quick, but a different convention. Wikipedia has a nice list of Windows/MacOSX equivalents: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts#Text_editing

Comment: Also, open menu with Ctrl+F2? Ick. I'm all for using keyboard shortcuts, but opening, navigating, and selecting menus with the keyboard is backwards. Here's a trick that's better: command-? to open help search menu, start typing the menu command you're searching for, down arrow to select it.

Comment: @ghoppe, I think your assumption of NetBeans being "a brain-dead cross-platform java application" is a flawed judgement and incorrect. Use of the OPTION key IS legal as a shortcut, and is throughout OSX, such as OPTION+COMMAND+C to copy style. A better reasoning would be to state that OPTION is not to be used exclusively for shortcuts.

Comment: @Brett I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, but that was my implication, wasn't it? **Of course** you can use OPTION *with* a button shortcut. You can use SHIFT with a shortcut too. But does that make it "legal as a shortcut?" NO. It's legal as a shortcut modifier, just like shift. No one would say SHIFT is legal as a shortcut.

Comment: This question on StackOverflow is the same question with roughly the same answer that more explicitly answers the (perhaps edited later) question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876485/how-to-disable-typing-special-characters-when-pressing-option-key-in-mac-os-x

Comment: If this was an ; it is another one of their stupidest decision to forcefully innovate. Only have CMD + CTRL for shortcuts on Macbooks is stupid because there's a single CTRL so that means you cannot press more than half of the key while holding CTRL. Ergonomic keyboard finger placement dictates to use two hand for shortcut presses when they're on different halfs hence we have two of modifier keys. Otherwise keyboard manufacturers would save money not including those extra keys. I hate ignorant decision like this which are rampant in this company. They're also too proud to admit they're wrong!

Comment: "This is a much more sane and reasonable approach to extended characters than windows alt-numpad tricks." This got you my downvote because it's a highly opinionated statement and it does not answer the question.

Comment: @ThaJay let me introduce to fanpersonism - the problem is always that you are doing it wrong, not that mac should let you do it.

Answer (score 10):

I have a much better solution than creating own custom keyboards: just use the "Unicode Hex Input" input source. It's the regular QWERTY minus all this weird stuff on the ⌥ button.

Not sure which OS version it is available from though. If you have any information about this, feel free to edit it into the answer.

Comment: But Option+A _could_ be the start of a hex value input (like Option+A+A+A+A [yields](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/aaaa) ꪪ), so are you sure that pressing Option+A is also propagated to whatever program has focus? (Also note that this also disables the press-and-hold functionality to show accented characters for the character that is long-pressed, along with the great option to just press a number to select one. But indeed, this seems quite a simple solution if one does not want all that, and if it works.)

Comment: @Arjan Definitely propagates to at least my IDE (Android Studio/IntelliJ IDEA). I don't need any accented characters in my code for obvious reasons, should be the same for most other developers. If you use accented characters elsewhere, then yeah, apparently you'd have to set up a separate input source for that.

Comment: Then it's a nice solution indeed!

Comment: Note that this unfortunately disables the option+← and option+→ word-delimited keyboard navigation shortcuts, for some reason.

Comment: @j6m8 I had to use Karabiner to make this work. Until I set it up the way I want it, text input had been a constant source of frustration on a Mac for me. Windows never gave me any of these problems, for instance.

Comment: @Malcolm macOS is increasingly painful with every new release... You may be able to override this in your `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`, using [this cheatsheet](https://gist.github.com/trusktr/1e5e516df4e8032cbc3d). But yeah, that's absurd. Curious to hear what karabiner config you've used; I can't find option+arrow configs...

Comment: @j6m8 Nice approach, thanks for sharing this! I've just created the config myself, I can probably share it tomorrow, it's on my work notebook.

Comment: @j6m8 I've put [my config on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/DrMetallius/99e5a6d8a19841088cbf8bc6d137a50a?ts=4). Maybe it can help you or someone else.

Comment: Simple and effective solution.

Answer (score 1):

The question also appears here on StackOverflow 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876485/how-to-disable-typing-special-characters-when-pressing-option-key-in-mac-os-x

On that question, I found Dan's answer to go to [wordherd.com](http://wordherd.com/keyboards/) and generate a keyboard map without the [option] key shortcuts to be the quickest and easiest solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16019737/266531