# How do I disable special character combinations (option+shift+) in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop using Mac keyboard Option as a modifier to character](https://superuser.com/questions/151373/stop-using-mac-keyboard-option-as-a-modifier-to-character)

I use NetBeans as my IDE and I'm trying to map <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to fix imports and <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to reformat code, but it keeps inserting ˆ (with <kbd>I</kbd>) and Ï (<kbd>F</kbd>). This is something that Mac OS X is doing, because it even does it in this browser window.

Is there a way to disable this? I know it's handy to press <kbd>OPTION</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> for example to get a ˆ in some circumstances, but I'd prefer to map that to <kbd>OPTION</kbd><kbd>CONTROL</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> instead.

Comment: Use `Ctrl`, `Cmd`, or `Ctrl-Cmd` instead.

Comment: Duplicate? http://superuser.com/questions/151373/stop-using-mac-keyboard-option-as-a-modifier-to-character

Comment: @Daniel, thanks, I have chosen to use COMMAND, however, the problem is that I accidentally sometimes press OPTION at the same time as the keys are close together, I don't realise, leave the file and find later that I've got a rogue character in my source code.