# Option as meta key EVERYWHERE?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs

I can set this option in the Terminal app, but I'd like to do this in other apps as well.

Surprisingly, most apps support a subset of emacs commands, but anything related to the meta key ends up as a special character like ƒ.

Comment: I suppose you want to use "option" as meta key so you can jump over words with "option + F" and "Option + B". Out of curiosity, what other Mac App do you want to benefit this kind of shortcut?

Comment: @Yoric literally anything with a text editor. Such as the text box I'm typing into right now.

Comment: @Zach there are some workarounds like the Firenvim extension to edit text in a web browser using (neo)vim. Or VimMode spoon (Hammerspoon), which is fantastic to get all the basics vim movements almost anywhere in macOS. Karabiner is also useful to customise shortcuts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop using Mac keyboard Option as a modifier to character](https://superuser.com/questions/151373/stop-using-mac-keyboard-option-as-a-modifier-to-character)